# What's a good unix editor to use with SSH on a typical smart phone?

Tags: unix, editor, smartphone

I'm an emacs user considering getting a smartphone. I notice that a lot of the phone keyboards don't have extended keyboard keys (I mean thinks like ctr and esc). What editors do you smartphone people use if you have to connect to the server by ssh and do an emergency repair? I was thinking VI would be a good choice since you mostly just need "esc" and you might be able to map something else to it.

I'm not looking to start doing all my development over the phone, but I need a good editor for those times when it's the only option.

Suggestions please!

Comment: Most smartphones tend to come with touchscreens these days, so if you use a good terminal app you might be able to get those extra keys on the screen. For instance, my N900's default terminal app lets you customize the row of special keys displayed at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decent ssh client should give you access to those keys.  Even a vi user needs to have control key combinations.

Answer (score 3):

If you're really hardcore, you can learn how to use `ex`, which is a non-visual version of vi.  You do not even need any escape or control keys to edit.  You don't have to rely on your terminal emulator emulating a terminal correctly.  You can append text or use `s///` to change text within lines.
For example:

```
$ cp /etc/services test.txt
$ ex test.txt
"test.txt" 576L, 18832C
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:p
# Local services
:/finger
finger          79/tcp
:s/finger/toe/
toe             79/tcp
:wq
```

Comment: It would be even more hardcore to use ed. :-)

Comment: Not sure I'm that hardcore. :/

Answer (score 1):

I use midpSSH to connect from my blackberry pearl to our HP UX server and I use vim for short editing.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is a lot easier if you attach a keyboard to your smartphone (via bluetooth, usb or otherwise).